# Obtaining steady state solution for spring mass dashpot system

Tags: matlab, math

I'm trying to solve the following problem using MATLAB but I faced multiple issues. The plot I obtained doesn't seem right even though I tried to obtain the steady-state solution, I got a plot that doesn't look steady.

The problem I'm trying to solve

[image: The problem I'm trying to solve]

The incorrect plot I got.

[image: Incorrect plot I obtained]

and here is the code

```
% system parameters
m=1; k=1; c=.1; wn=sqrt(k/m); z=c/2/sqrt(m*k); wd=wn*sqrt(1-z^2);

% initial conditions
x0=0; v0=0;

%% time
dt=.001; tMax=8*pi; t=0:(tMax-0)/999:tMax;

% input
A=1
omega=(2*pi)/10

F=A/2-(4*A/pi^2)*cos(omega*t); Fw=fft(F);
F=k*A*cos(omega*t); Fw=fft(F);
% normalize
y = F/m;

% compute coefficients proportional to the Fourier series coefficients
Yw = fft(y);

% setup the equations to solve the particular solution of the differential equation 
% by the method of undetermined coefficients
N=1000
T=10
k = [0:N/2];
w = 2*pi*k/T;
A = wn*wn-w.*w;
B = 2*z*wn*w;

% solve the equation [A B;-B A][real(Xw); imag(Xw)] = [real(Yw); imag(Yw)] equation
% Note that solution can be obtained by writing [A B;-B A] as a scaling + rotation
% of a 2D vector, which we solve using complex number algebra
C = sqrt(A.*A+B.*B);
theta = acos(A./C);
Ywp = exp(j*theta)./C.*Yw([1:N/2+1]);

% build a hermitian-symmetric spectrum
Xw = [Ywp conj(fliplr(Ywp(2:end-1)))];

% bring back to time-domain (function synthesis from Fourier Series coefficients)
x = ifft(Xw);
figure()
plot(t,x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your forcing function doesn't look like the triangle wave in the problem. I edited the `%% time` section of your code into the following and appeared to give a steady state response.

```
%% time
TP = 10; % forcing time period (10 s)
dt=.001; 
tMax= 3*TP; % needs to be multiple of the time period
t=0:(tMax-0)/999:tMax;

% input
A=1; % Forcing amplitude
omega=(2*pi)/TP;

% forcing is a triangle wave
% generate a triangle wave with min/max values of 0/1. 
F = 0*t;
for i = 1:length(t)
    if mod(t(i), TP) <= TP/2
        F(i) = mod(t(i), TP)/(TP/2);
    else
        F(i) = 2 - mod(t(i), TP)/(TP/2);
    end
end
F = F*A; % scale triangle wave by amplitude

% you can also use MATLAB's sawtooth() function if you have the signal
% processing toolbox
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Micheal so I tried the code with a simple Harmonic function and still got a unsteady answer.

Comment: You'll need to tell me what function you tried, and perhaps a link to an image of your result. For the example forcing in your question (k A cos( omega t )), you need to make sure the total simulation time is an integer multiple of the time period (i.e. a multiple of 10s). Also, make sure the simulation time is long enough to see slow changes. Using this forcing and choosing TMax = 20*TP, I get the following plot: https://imgur.com/a/GDQsQzt     . If your simulation time is too short (say 20s), you don't see the slow oscillatory behaviour of the system.